# How to compare the syllable structures of Chinese with Hangul?

Tags: pinyin

How to compare the syllable structures (or pronunciations) of Chinese (Standard or Pu3Tong1Hua4) with Hangul (Korea Language)?

In this article [here](https://forum.unilang.org/viewtopic.php?t=24384), it says, "The number of the theoretically possible Modern Hangul syllables is: 11,172. Initial consonant 19 * Middle vowel 21 * (Final consonant 27 + No final 1) = 11,172.

My question is how come Korea has so many "Final consonants" (or Coda) while Chinese has only two (-n, -ng)?

Comment: There used to be a few more, they have been lost in history, but still preserved in some dialects. Experts in phonology can give you a more detailed story.